What is the product topology on $\{ 1, \ldots, k \}^{\mathbb R}$? How does Tychonoff’s theorem imply that it is compact?
I'm not well-versed in topology and encountered this as part of a larger argument about coloring the real numbers:
"An arbitrary Cartesian product of compact topological spaces is compact (Tychonoff's Theorem), and in particular, the space $M$ of all mappings $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow [k]$ is compact." (Here, $k$ is a positive integer and $[k] = \{1, \ldots, k\}$.)
The topology they define on this space is "that of the Cartesian power $[k]^{\mathbb{R}}$"; I am not familiar with this topology.
I don't see the connection between Tychonoff's Theorem and the statement. In other words, in what sense is $M$ a Cartesian product of compact topological spaces? This confuses me because the elements of $M$ are mappings, and it is not clear to me how a mapping itself could be an element of a Cartesian product.

How do you define an arbitrary cartesian product?

@Kandinskij This is part of a proof I saw in some lecture notes, and they don't define it anywhere so I'm not entirely sure, but I'd assume that "arbitrary Cartesian product" means n-ary Cartesian product between any n compact topological spaces

You need to supply more context, ideally, a reference to the paper or book you are reading. To say the space of all mappings $f : \Bbb{R} \to [k]$ is compact only makes sense if we are given a topology on that space: what is that topology? Almost certainly here, that is the product topology on $[k]^{\Bbb{R}}$ where $[k]$ is equipped with the discrete topology, but you haven't given us enough concept to be sure of that.

@RobArthan Yes, the topology they define on this space is "that of the Cartesian power $[k]^{\mathbb{R}}$" It's from these notes, at the bottom of page 39: https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~15850/handouts/matousek-vondrak-prob-ln.pdf

The cartesian product of a family of sets indexed by $I$ is defined as the set of mappings from $I$ to the union of those sets such that each element of $I$ is mapped inside the set indexed by it. If all sets in the family are equal, this condition is trivially satisfied and the product is simply the set of mappings from $I$ to that set. In your example $I=\mathbb R$ and the sets are all identical to $[k].$
The topology implied when taking a product of topological spaces is the topology of pointwise convergence (this is synonymous with "product topology"). It is generated by products of open subsets where all but a finite number of subsets are equal to the full set.
If $[k]$ is equipped with the discrete topology, all its subsets are open. A typical open neighbourhood of a function $f$ then consists of all functions that have the same value as $f$ at a given finite set of real numbers and arbitrary values (in $[k]$) elsewhere.

That first part helps a lot! In the notes where this came from, they go on to say, "any set of mappings of the form {f \in M: f(i) = g(i) for all i \in I}, where I is a finite subset of R and g: I \rightarrow [k] is arbitrary, is closed in M." I assume they are doing something different, using the set of functions you mention to define the topology in terms of closed sets instead of open neighborhoods? Or am I misunderstanding how this is another case of the "typical" open neighborhood you mention?

They can do that because the discrete topology does not distinguish between open and closed subsets: all subsets of $[k]$ are both closed and open. The complement of your closed set is ${f\in M:\exists i\in I, f(i)\neq g(i)}=\cup_{i\in I}{f\in M:f(i)\neq g(i)}=\cup_{i\in I, x\in([k]\setminus g(i))}{f\in M:f(i)=x}$ which is a finite union of my open sets and therefore open. Conversely, the complement of any of my open sets can be written as a finite intersection of your closed sets.
